# Можно ли устранить двусмысленности метода через virtual?

Tags: c++, наследование

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student() {}
    ~Student() {}
    void show()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << surname << endl;
        cout << "Group: " << group << endl;
    }
    void set_name(string Name) { name = Name; }
    void set_surname(string Surname) { surname = Surname; }
    void set_group(string Group) { group = Group; }
protected:
    string name, surname;
    string group;
};

class Teacher
{
public:
    Teacher() : salary(0) {}
    ~Teacher() {}
    void show()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << surname << endl;
        cout << "Degree: " << degree << endl;
        cout << "Salary: " << salary << endl;
    }
    void set_name(string Name) { name = Name; }
    void set_surname(string Surname) { surname = Surname; }
    void set_degree(string Degree) { degree = Degree; }
    void set_salary(double Salary) { salary = Salary; }
protected:
    string name, surname;
    string degree;
    double salary;
};

class Undergraduate : public Student
{
public:
    Undergraduate() {}
    ~Undergraduate() {}
};

class Postgraduate: virtual public Undergraduate
{
public:
    Postgraduate() {}
    ~Postgraduate() {}
};

class TeachingAssistant: public Teacher, public Postgraduate
{
public:
    TeachingAssistant(){}
    ~TeachingAssistant(){}
};


int main()
{
    TeachingAssistant ta;
    ta.show();
}
```

Вот в таком куске кода требуется убрать двусмысленность методов show,set_name_set_surname

Вроде пробовал подставлять `vritual` наследование почти во все места, но всё еще не работает. Насколько я знаю, `virtual` помогает убрать двусмысленность при наследовании чего-то дважды, но это что-то - элемент одного базового класса.

Поможет ли `virtual` при том, что методы идут от разных классов, но называются по разному? Если нет, то как лучше поступить?

Comment: Может, `Student` и `Teacher` должны наследоваться от одного абстрактного базового класса?

Comment: @mkkik учитывая пересечение по полям имя/фамилия скорее даже не совсем абстрактного.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, вы правы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ta.Student::show();
```

Но вообще-то обычно это говорит о плохом проекте...

Если хотите вызывать просто

```
ta.show();
```

то создайте такую функцию к классе `TeachingAssistant`, а в ней вызывайте нужную вам функцию предка.

Встречал мнения разных гуру типа Саттера, кажется, что лучше вообще множественным наследованием не увлекаться.

Comment: Увлекаться наследованием, особенно множественным, не стоит, но нередко они полезны...(не в данном случаи)